# Авторизовать гостя под скрытым пользователем

Tags: laravel

Есть необходимость вместо того чтобы использовать неавторизированного юзера, делать автоматический вход под одним пользователем `MyTestUser` и работать от его имени.

Как и куда внедрить эту авторизацию чтобы всё остальное работало так же как если бы этот пользователь залогинился самостоятельно?

Answer (score -1):

Можно просто где угодно авторизовать пользователя с определенным ID.

К примеру, вы создаете пользователя `MyTestUser` с ID 1, на определенной странице делаете вызов метода:

```
Auth::loginUsingId(1, true);
```

И теперь этот пользователь авторизован, второй параметр отвечает за `remember me`.